# word or phrase for life expectancy increase beyond 1 year per year, resulting in effective immortality

Tags: vocabulary

I heard a term or phrase recently (which I can't remember or find now) that indicates an age (or future year of birth) where technology and medicine will cause life expectancy to rise at a rate >= 1 year per year, resulting in effective immortality.

I can't remember if it's an adjective or a noun.

Is there a term for this or related to this?

Comment: Was the term used in a scientific journal or in a Sci-fi story? Did you have to look up its meaning (i.e. is it uncommon)?  Did the author actually use the term *immortality* in the article (story), or is/was that your natural assumption?

Comment: It's a new term, used in discussions about advanced technology and futurology.    It reminded me of "uncanny valley" (robotics)

Comment: Or maybe it's not new and that's just the first time I heard it. It could have come from sci-fi.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. Think about it. You're born and life expectancy is 80. Life expectancy increases by one year per year. By the time you're 80 life expectancy is 160. That doesn't mean you're expected to live another 80 years (160 minus 80), because the less medically advanced environment you've been living in the first 80 years of your life may well have made any increase in life expectancy negligible. Life expectancy should be measured from start of life.

Comment: @Zebrafish I think op refers to increase in [curtate life expectation](http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/b.d.rickayzen/wright%20contingencies%20notes.pdf), which is (in your example) the life expectancy of someone who was born 80 years ago and is still alive today. This is not the same as the life expectancy of someone who was born 80 years ago because _still being alive_ adds more information. It's similar to a [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the phrase I was looking for!

**"[Longevity escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longevity_escape_velocity)"**

> ...a hypothetical situation in which life expectancy is being extended longer than the time that is passing. For example, in a given year in which longevity escape velocity would be maintained, technological advances would increase life expectancy more than the year that just went by.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you’re looking for is [**amortality**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/amortal) and the Collins definition says:

> pursuing a lifestyle that defies the process of ageing

which, in short, equates to immortality but with the proviso that accidental death can still occur. That is, you won’t die from age related complications but you could still be run over by a bus.

According to [theUrbanDictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=amortal), it’s explored in the (non-fiction) book: "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind" and, there, means:

> Unable to die from disease or age. Immortal if no physical ailment befalls you.

If I recall correctly, in the book, the implications on car and accident insurance are examined - people suddenly become much more fearful of death if it is no longer an inevitability and this pushes up costs.

Comment: The Collins definition (and please attribute correctly) seems a long way away from that given in UD. Collins is almost always taken as the more authoritative source, and 'pursuing a lifestyle that defies the process of ageing' does not match well with OP's request. Though I suspect they're after something not recognised as part of the lexicon.

Comment: Thanks for the kind mentoring @EdwinAshworth, I've edited it. I agree that the Urban Dictionary isn't a great source, but I think this word is a relatively new variation on "immortal" and "Sapiens:..." is a decent book which does explore the implications of an effectively ever living society (i.e. life expectancy is infinite barring accidental death).

Comment: There's a discussion [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116553/is-it-possible-to-defy-the-laws-of-physics) as to the various senses 'defies' has. Here, the problem with the Collins definition of 'amortality' is as to whether it is meant to mean 'defeats'.  It doesn't necessarily mean 'overcome'; it could be the 'put up active resistance to' sense. So Collins could be read as 'adopting a healthy lifestyle'.